# How to extend Context or Provider in ReactJS to display a Loading Spinner

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-context

I would like to add a loading spinner during transitions. For example, when the app is fetching if the user is authenticated. How can this additional variable be added to the **Context(Provider)**?

My idea was to extend my `AuthProvider` (see below) with an additional variable, but its unclear to me if this is a good practice, and also if it can be actually consumed properly. The below example resulted that the variable `loading` is always `false` in the `Consumer.js`:

*See `[PartX]` linked to my comment above.*

**App.js**

```
import { AuthProvider } from "./auth/firebase/AuthProvider";

function App() {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
        <p>
           Hello <code>world</code>
        </p>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}
```

**AuthProvider.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import auth from "./configAuth";

export const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);  // <--- [PartX]

  useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(setUser, setLoading(false));  // <--- [PartX]
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user }}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

**Consumer.js**

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Menu from "@mui/material/Menu";
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";

import { SignInButton, SignOutButton } from "../sign-in/SignInModal";
import { AuthContext } from "../firebase/AuthProvider";

export default function ProfileBox() {

  /* General Anchor Clicks */
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };
  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  /* Auth state */
  const { user, loading } = useContext(AuthContext);

  // [PartX] ----> Does not work, always False
  console.log(loading)

  if (!user) {
    return (
      <SignInButton />
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button
          color="inherit"
          id="basic-button"
          aria-controls={open ? 'basic-menu' : undefined}
          aria-haspopup="true"
          aria-expanded={open ? 'true' : undefined}
          onClick={handleClick}
        >
          {user.displayName}
        </Button>
        <Menu
          disableScrollLock={true}
          id="basic-menu"
          anchorEl={anchorEl}
          open={open}
          onClose={handleClose}
          MenuListProps={{
            'aria-labelledby': 'basic-button',
          }}
        >
          <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}> <SignOutButton /></MenuItem>
        </Menu>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: From a design point of view, a "spinner" feature should not be thought of as part of authentication. They serve two different purposes. So, if you consider making a `<Spinner>` wrapper component, you could wrap those components requiring a spinner. Then the Spinner component would boolean in or out.

Comment: Agree, but you need to know when it needs to opt in and out, i.e. when making the call to Firebase to check if the user is authenticated, and the progress of that request is part of the AuthProvider. So how we share that progress through the context provider?

Comment: Re-read "Thinking in React". The point is that the authentication system should only be responsible for indicating "logged in" is `true` or `false`. By lifting that state up, as you have, other components can take advantage of that boolean. So the `<Spinner>` component could be one of those components. The goal is separation of concerns. The `<Spinner>` is shown or not shown, the user is logged in or not logged in. The idea is to share state amongst components - not tightly couple "logged in" and "spinner". Hope that helps.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I appreciate the way you challenged me to find the answer. While rereading I got the “aha” moment, and I will draft an answer in the next days here with references to that article.